# Akka-Stream stream within stream

Tags: akka-stream

I am trying to figure out how to handle a situation where in one of your stage you need to make a call that return an InputStream, where I would deal with that stream as a Source of the stage that comes further down.

e.g.

```
 Source.map(e => Calls that return an InputStream)
 .via(processingFlow).runwith(sink.ignore)
```

I would like that the element going to Processing flow as those coming from the InputStream. This is basically a situation where I am tailing a file, reading each line, the line give me the information about a call I need to make against a CLI api, when making that call I get the Stdout as an InputStream from which to read the result. Result are going to be huge most of the time, so I can just collect the all thing in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can use `StreamConverters` utilities to get `Source`s and `Sink`s from java.io streams. More info [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#additional-sink-and-source-converters).
- you can use `flatMapConcat` or `flatMapMerge` to flatten a stream of `Source`s into a single stream. More info [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#flatmapconcat).

A quick example could be:

```
  val source: Source[String, NotUsed] = ???
  def gimmeInputStream(name: String): InputStream = ???
  val processingFlow: Flow[ByteString, ByteString, NotUsed] = ???

  source
    .map(gimmeInputStream)
    .flatMapConcat(is ⇒ StreamConverters.fromInputStream(() ⇒ is, chunkSize = 8192))
    .via(processingFlow)
    .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

However Akka Streams offers a more idiomatic DSL to read/write files in the `FileIO` object. More info [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#file-io-sinks-and-sources).

The example becomes:

```
  val source: Source[String, NotUsed] = ???
  val processingFlow: Flow[ByteString, ByteString, NotUsed] = ???

  source
    .flatMapConcat(name ⇒ FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get(name)))
    .via(processingFlow)
    .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```